# Пользователь вводит 10 слов в массив. Найдите первое слово, в котором есть две гласные буквы подряд

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Помогите решить задачу:

> 1. Пользователь вводит 10 слов в массив. Найдите первое слово, в котором есть две гласные буквы подряд

Начал её решать с помощью циклов, но застрял.

Мне чем проще, тем лучше, можно `StringBuilder` использовать, но желательно без коллекций и патернов, еще не проходили

```java
public class Dz1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите 10 слов:");
        String[] arr = new String[10];
        char[] ch = {'а','е','ё','и','о','у','э','ю','ы','я'};
        String str1 = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            String str = sc.next();
            arr[i] = str;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr[i].length() ; i++) {

            char[] ch1 = arr[i].toCharArray();

            for (int j = 0; j < ch.length ; j++) {

                for (int k = 0; k < ch1.length - 1; k++) {

                    if (ch[j] == ch1[k] & ch[j] == ch1[k + 1]) {
                        str1 = arr[i];
                        System.out.println(str1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: непонятна суть вопроса и непонятна суть проблемы. Бери по две буквы подряд в каждом слове и смотри. Зачем тут аж тройной вложенный цикл?

Comment: @АлексейФилиппов, а с какой целью вы задаёте свои вопросы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея хорошая, но подсчёт пар гласных написан неправильно, так как условие `if (ch[j] == ch1[k] & ch[j] == ch1[k + 1])` проверяет, что есть пара *одинаковых* гласных, а не любых из массива `ch`.

Следует завести счётчик гласных *для каждого слова*, увеличивать его при обнаружении гласной буквы и соответственно сбрасывать при обнаружении согласной буквы.  Как только значение счётчика достигнет двух, выходить из вложенного цикла при помощи `break label`.  Также следует учесть, что буквы в слове не обязательно строчные.

Цикл поиска по массиву гласных лучше заменить улучшенным оператором `switch`.

Вариант реализации:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите 10 слов:");
String[] arr = new String[10];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = sc.next();
}

String twoVowels = null;
out: for (var word : arr) {
    var vowelCount = 0;
    
    for (var c : word.toCharArray()) {
        switch(Character.toLowerCase(c)) {
            case 'а','е','ё','и','о','у','ы','э','ю','я' -> {
                if (++vowelCount == 2) {
                    twoVowels = word;
                    break out;
                }
            }
            default -> vowelCount = 0;
        };
    }
}
if (null == twoVowels) {
    System.out.println("Слово НЕ найдено");
} else {
    System.out.println("Слово найдено: " + twoVowels);
}
```

---

Возможно и более короткое решение с одним циклом по входным словам с использованием метода `String::matches`, для которого нужно задать шаблон в виде регулярного выражения (массив гласных `ch` не нужен).

```java
// ... ввод массива arr
String twoVowels = null;
for (String word : arr) {
    if (word.matches("(?ui).*[аеёиоуыэюя]{2,}.*")) {
        twoVowels = word;
        break;
    }
}
if (null == twoVowels) {
    System.out.println("Слово НЕ найдено");
} else {
    System.out.println("Слово найдено: " + twoVowels);
}
```

В регулярном выражении `"(?ui).*[аеёиоуэюыя]{2,}.*"`

- `(?ui)` - отключить проверку регистра букв
- `.*` - пропустить любую последовательность символов в начале / конце слова
- `[аеёиоуэюыя]{2,}` - две и более подряд идущих гласных

Аналогично, вместо указания флажков `(?ui)` можно было бы записать прописные гласные в квадратных скобках `".*[аеёиоуыэюяAЕЁИОУЫЭЮЯ]{2,}.*"`.
С использованием Stream API решение выглядит так:

```java
String twoVowels = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .filter(w -> w.matches(".*[аеёиоуэюыяАЕЁИОУЫЭЮЯ]{2,}.*"))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```